# No Response For Page With FB PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's very strange. But when we use the exact same GET request of the Facebook Graph API *in PHP*, it doesn't work.

Any idea why this isn't working with PHP?

---

**GET request with explorer:** (works)

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=BucutiTaraBeachResortAruba&version=v2.3&

---

**Get request with PHP API:** (doesn't work)

```
new FacebookRequest(
  $this->session,
  'GET',
  ‘/BucutiTaraBeachResortAruba’,
  ['fields' => 'id,name,link'],
  'v2.3'
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Response: [FacebookRequestException](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequestException)  *(any idea why it's not working?)*

> Exception occured, code: 100 with message: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api; path = /BucutiTaraBeachResortAruba

Comment: The same PHP request works for other FB IDs, for example it works for `gornergrat`

Comment: @WizKid The (secret) access token from our app.

Comment: _“Unsupported get request”_ often means that you have no right to see/read the object that you are trying to access. For a page, that might depend on the page’s settings/restrictions – if its visibility is limited in any way, then you need a user access token of a user that is allowed to see it.

Comment: Thank you, @CBroe - I think that's it. It's strange, however, that it is possible to even do that on Facebook for (company) pages?

Comment: It is working for me just as your code describes it. Have you checked that your `$this->session` is set up correctly? As @CBroe says, this error is common when a certain object cannot be queried due to permissions not being set up properly. If this is the case here, I'd point to the session as the culprit.